# Broken markup when using the_excerpt() in a widget?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

The text returned by the_excerpt() does not respect my widget format. I couldn't explain it better so I will just show you my code:

```
function widget($args, $options) {
    extract($args);

    $post_type = $options['post_type'];
    $num_of_posts = $options['limit'];

    // Create a new instance
    $second_query = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => "$post_type",
                        'posts_per_page' => "$num_of_posts",
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                    ) ); 

    // The Loop
    if ($second_query->have_posts()) :
      while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post();
          $byh_content .= "<p>" . the_excerpt() . "</p>";
      endwhile; else :
          $byh_content = "<p>No " . $options['post_type'] . "s found.</p>";
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $title = "<h3>" . $options['title'] . "</h3>";
    $content = $byh_content;

    echo $before_widget.$title.$content.$after_widget;
}
```

The result isn't what I expected. Here's what it looks like when rendered:

[image: widget rendered]

The title should be at the top. The reason is that, the excerpt isn't where it is supposed to be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are working with strings, you need to use a function which returns the value, instead of echoing it;
in this line:

`$byh_content .= "<p>" . the_excerpt() . "</p>";`

use `get_the_excerpt()`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Comment: Could you please enlighten me why my method isn't working? :-\

Comment: `the_excerpt()` is echoing (showing) the truncated content immediately where it is used in the code, instead returning it (passing it) to the string variable. there are general (not always) two types of wordpress functions - those starting with `the_` that output the results, and the others starting with `get_` that return the results.